# Setting of Parallelism-count for apache storm bolt?

Tags: apache-storm

I'm running a 8 core machine with 4 worker slots, I had 10 bolts. As per my knowledge each bolt uses a single executor by default. I.e.: my 8 core has only eight executors. Is it Right or Wrong? If Right how to set Parallelism-count for my 10 bolts, if Wrong, what’s the Right way to set Parallelism?

Answer (score 1):

Understand it this way:
One node (server) has one supervisor.
Supervisor starts/stops workers.
Worker is a process.
Executors are threads in the worker process.
One executor can run multiple tasks.
A task is an instance of your spout or bolt.
The number of executors is always less than or equal to the number of tasks.

So now, it doesn't matter how many cores your machine has. Go ahead and create as many executors as the number of bolts you have. Storm will use a thread pool to manage the threading, so your tasks will be time shared on your processor automatically.

If you create more than 1 worker and you have a second supervisor node, then that supervisor will run maybe 5 of your 10 bolts under one worker and the first supervisor will run maybe 5 of your 10 bolts under another worker.

There is no right and wrong way to set up parallelism. It's highly dependent on what kind of logic you want to program.